# String not decrypted properly using <openssl/aes>

Tags: c++, c, linux, encryption, openssl

I want to write one simple a program that will encrypt one test using `<openssl/aes.h>` and at the same time decrypt it. I wrote below program

Adding my whole code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    //encryption testing
    unsigned char inputb[2048] = {'\0'};
    unsigned char encpb[2048]= {'\0'};
    unsigned char opb[2048]= {'\0'};
#define MAX_SIZE 100

    unsigned char oneKey[] = "6BC1BEE22E409F96E93D7E117393172A";
    AES_KEY key; 
    AES_KEY key1; 

    char testchat[] = "!!!test doctors file!!! @Hospitan name(norman) SICKAPP_NAME=9873471093 @Duration (Duration\
    of doctor visitdfwhedf in months)higibujiji TESTATION=-5 #Expiry date MADICINE_NAME=678041783478\n";
    char NULL_byte[16] = {0};
    memcpy((char*)inputb, (testchat), strlen(testchat)+1);
    printf("\n\ninputb= %s strlen(testchat)=%d \n\n",inputb, strlen(testchat));
    AES_set_encrypt_key(oneKey, 128, &key);
    unsigned char tmp_char[50] = {'\0'};
    char* pChar = (char*)inputb;
    unsigned char tmp_char_encpb[MAX_SIZE];
    while(*pChar != '\0') {
        memset(tmp_char, '\0',  50);
        memset(tmp_char_encpb, '\0',  MAX_SIZE);
        if(strlen(pChar) < 16)  {
            strncpy((char*)tmp_char, (char*)pChar, strlen(pChar)+1);
            strncat((char*)tmp_char, NULL_byte, 16 - strlen(pChar)+1);
        }
        else
            strncpy((char*)tmp_char, (char*)pChar, 16);
        printf("Line:%d tmp_char = %s pChar=%d\n", __LINE__, tmp_char, strlen(pChar));
        AES_encrypt(tmp_char, tmp_char_encpb, &key);
        strcat((char*)encpb, (char*)tmp_char_encpb);

        pChar += 16;
    }
    printf("len encpb=%d\n", strlen((char*)encpb));
    //now test with decrypting  and check if all okk....
    unsigned char oneKey1[] = "6BC1BEE22E409F96E93D7E117393172A";
    AES_set_decrypt_key(oneKey1,128,&key1);
    unsigned char tmp_char_dencpb[MAX_SIZE];
    pChar = (char*)encpb;
    while(*pChar != '\0') {
        memset(tmp_char, '\0',  50);
        if(strlen(pChar) < 16)  {
            strncpy((char*)tmp_char, (char*)pChar, strlen(pChar)+1);
            strncat((char*)tmp_char, NULL_byte, 16 - strlen(pChar)+1);
        }
        else
            strncpy((char*)tmp_char, (char*)pChar, 16);
        AES_decrypt(tmp_char, tmp_char_dencpb, &key1);
        strncat((char*)opb, (char*)tmp_char_dencpb,16);
        memset(tmp_char_dencpb, '\0',  MAX_SIZE);
        pChar += 16;
    }

    printf("\n\nopb = %s\n\n",opb);
    return 0;
}
```

I am building via:

```
g++ mytest.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

running through GDB:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003e48437122 in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.4-3.el6.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.9-22.el6_2.1.x86_64 libcom_err-1.41.12-11.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 libselinux-2.0.94-5.2.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64 openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.4.x86_64 zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000003e48437122 in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000400e9b in GetExpiryDate (exp_date=0x7fffffffd970) at LicReader.cpp:66
#2  0x0000000000400eeb in IsLicenseExpired () at LicReader.cpp:74
#3  0x0000000000400f3b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffda88) at LicReader.cpp:86
(gdb)
```

OP: in out put some time I got current decrypted string and some time getting with junk character.(when i/p string changed)

Am I missed something anywhere? Can anyone tell why AES_decrypt  not workin gsometimes?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: AES_decrypt not working some times...

Answer (score 1):

Zero-terminated string manipulation is not how to manage encrypted data... for example you're using `strcat` to add encrypted data to `encpb`... but what happens if there's a zero in the encrypted data?  What happens is you don't get all the data.  Deal instead with the actual block-size which is 16 bytes.  What happens if the data you encrypt is not a multiple of 16 bytes?  You have to pad it out to a multiple of 16.  How?  Lots of different ways, like PKCS7.  Plus you should look into cipher-block-chaining and salting... lots to learn!